# Return available rooms depending 2 others tables

Tags: mysql

Here my table structure:

___Rooms

```
|--------|----------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_Name |
|--------|----------|
|      1 |     Blue |
|      2 |      Red |
|      3 |   Yellow |
|--------|----------|
```

___Rates

```
|--------|---------------|-------------|-----------|-------------------|---------------|
| RAT_Id | RAT_DateStart | RAT_DateEnd | RAT_Price | RAT_RoomsAffected | RAT_RoomsList |
|--------|---------------|-------------|-----------|-------------------|---------------|
|     90 |    2019-04-01 |  2019-05-01 |    139.00 |               all |               |
|     91 |    2019-05-01 |  2019-12-31 |    159.00 |              list |           1,2 |
|     92 |    2019-05-01 |  2019-12-31 |    129.00 |              list |             3 |
|--------|---------------|-------------|-----------|-------------------|---------------|
```

___Availabilities

```
|--------|------------|------------|------------|
| AVA_Id | AVA_RoomId | AVA_Status | AVA_Date   |
|--------|------------|------------|------------|
|    203 |          1 |       Open | 2019-04-01 |
|    204 |          1 |       Open | 2019-04-02 |
|    205 |          1 |       Open | 2019-04-03 |
|    206 |          1 |       Open | 2019-04-04 |
|    207 |          1 |       Open | 2019-04-05 |
|    208 |          1 |      Close | 2019-04-06 |
|    209 |          1 |      Close | 2019-04-07 |
|--------|------------|------------|------------|
```

---

Here's a quick description of these 3 tables:

- `_Rooms` contains informations about the rooms I can rent in my hotel.
- `___Rates` contains the rate informations I can apply for a special period and for rooms (if RAT_RoomsAffected is set to all it means that the rate can be applied for all the rooms I have in my hotel. If RAT_RoomsAffected is set to list, the rate could be applied only the the rooms id in the RAT_RoomsList field).
- `___Availabilities` list per day the possibility (Open) to book this room or the no possibility to book a room (Close).

---

My problem is the following:

I would like to list the rooms that respect the two following conditions:

- This rooms should be with the `Open` status (AVA_Status) for the dates a client wants to book in my hotel. For example, from the 2019-04-02 to the 2019-04-04 (2 nights).
- This rooms should be linked with a rate in `_Rates` table. So depending the client dates of stay I need to loop into this table and find a rate for this period.
- Finally the rates found should match the `ROO_Id` found in the first step. A `ROO_Id` could match if `RAT_RoomsAffected = all` or when this `ROO_Id` is found into the `RAT_RoomsList` list.

---

The desired output should be this one from the 2019-04-02 to the 2019-04-04:

```
|--------|----------|-----------|
| ROO_Id | ROO_Name | RAT_Price |
|--------|----------|-----------|
|      1 |     Blue |    139.00 |
|--------|----------|-----------|
```

---

This is the SQLFiddle to help you:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kPY6FmKw1SZJjTHUbLj5Pe/0

Thanks so much for any help I will receive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend that you either program this logic in your application or redesign your DB. Your tables look like they should be objects and the way everything is now, there's no easy way or elegant way to get the result you want, and you definitely can't do it in a single query. The most glaring thing is the RAT_RoomsList column, which is a string representing a list. Additionally, what would you do if the booking date range requested overlapped multiple rates?

---

#### Since this is tagged with mysql

The simplest solution I can think of would be to merge your Rates table into your Availabilities table, so that for every room and date combination, there is a rate as well. The Rates table would become redundant.

Then you can query:

```
SELECT AVA_RoomId, SUM(RAT_price)
FROM   ___Availabilities
WHERE  AVA_Status = 'Open' AND
       AVA_Date >= '2019-04-02' AND
       AVA_Date < '2019-04-04'
GROUP BY AVA_RoomId
HAVING COUNT(AVA_RoomId) = DATEDIFF('2019-04-04', '2019-04-02');
```

for the total price of the stay, or:

```
SELECT AVA_RoomId, AVA_Date, RAT_price
FROM   ___Availabilities
WHERE  AVA_Status = 'Open' AND
       AVA_Date >= '2019-04-02' AND
       AVA_Date < '2019-04-04';
```

for just a list of rooms and their rates that are open during the period, which you can sort through in your application.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kPY6FmKw1SZJjTHUbLj5Pe/2)